# Comunication between 2 prestashop stores

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to develop a module to comunicate 2 prestashop stores. One of them will be centralized store one.

I'll use webservices to interact between them but first step I need is know how to send a set of parameters between 2 prestashop installations; specifically I need to send prestashop store name, url and a webservice API Key I've generated.

Edit: I'm thinking on creating **new custom webservice** to send this parameters. Will be possible to create a custom one?

It will be recorded in an aditional table what will need to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself.

I've found a way to do a custom service overriding webservice request.

Into a new `modules\mymodule\override\classes\webservice\`folder I've created new `webservicerequest.php` class, extending from `WebserviceRequestCore`. There I can define my custom webservices.

Sorry for the inconvenience caused by this answer.